# Wordpress using 'www-data' as user in updates - how do I change this to another user?

Tags: linux, apache, wordpress, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have a Wordpress 3.2.1 install on an Amazon EC2 Ubuntu instance.
My Wordpress install is at

/var/www/blog/

Besides numerous issues I'm having with permissions etc, one thing that has stumped me is that when trying to do plugin updates, I get a window asking for FTP credentials. This is overridden by using

```
if(is_admin()) {
    add_filter('filesystem_method', create_function('$a', 'return "direct";' ));
    define( 'FS_CHMOD_DIR', 0751 );
}
```

at the end of wp-config.php.

But althought this allows for a full plugin update - without FTP credentials - I noticed on CLI that instead of my regular user `ubuntu` owning the files/folders of updated plugin, now it's `www-data` (Apache's daemon).

This is problematic since I am never logged in as `www-data` (and wouldn't want to) and then can't make any changes to the updated plugin.

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can install core control plugins this will help you lot and save your time too.

Here you can download core control plugins:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/core-control/

Hope this will help.